# Capital gain tax for selling house just bought?

Tags: real-estate, capital-gains-tax, tax-brackets

My wife and i just bought a house but due to new circumstances we may have to sell it less than a month after buying it (we cannot keep it vacant or rent it).

The house cost $160K. Say we sell it for the (extraordinary) price of $200K. From what I understand we would have to pay tax as we didn't live there for 2 years within the past 5 years. However considering our joint tax return, we are in the 15% bracket. Does that mean we would pay 0% tax on capital gain? If not, how much tax would we have to pay on this virtual sale of $200K?

Comment: What's your jurisdiction?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - given the reference to 15% bracket having a 0% long term gain, I had a high confidence they are US.

Comment: Yes this is in the US, and I am considered a US citizen for tax purposes, although I am originally from Europe. I have a follow up question to know if can benefit from partial tax exemption due to having a new job, and I assume it would be better suited to a new post.

Comment: For the follow up questions I created a new post [here](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/68134/partial-exclusion-from-short-term-capital-gain-due-to-change-of-job)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it appears you have a short term gain, less than one year holding period. Taxed at same rate at ordinary income. 15%, possibly pushing part of the number to 25%.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I had follow up questions, so I created a new post [here](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/68134/partial-exclusion-from-short-term-capital-gain-due-to-change-of-job).